# How to install BINGO on Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want to install BINGO cartridge on Postgresql in GCP. I've followed steps here https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres to install PostgreSQL 9.5.19 on Ubuntu. I downloaded the Bingo 1.8.0beta for PostgreSQL 9.5 from https://lifescience.opensource.epam.com/download/bingo.html. I followed these steps https://lifescience.opensource.epam.com/bingo/installation-manual-postgres.html#id2 to install but in vain.

```
<user>$ sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER
<user>$ createdb bingo;
<user>$ psql -U $USER -d bingo -f bingo-pg-install.sh
```

The error is as follows. I know I'm doing something very basic wrong. Can anyone please help me figure it out?

> psql:bingo-pg-install.sh:23: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "#!/"
>   LINE 1: #!/bin/sh
>           ^
>
> psql:bingo-pg-install.sh:48: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "then"
>   LINE 1: then
>           ^
>
> psql:bingo-pg-install.sh:53: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "case"
>   LINE 2:   case "$1" in
>             ^
>
> psql:bingo-pg-install.sh:57: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-" LINE
>   1: -libdir)
>           ^ psql:bingo-pg-install.sh:61: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-" LINE 1: -schema)
>           ^
>
> psql:bingo-pg-install.sh:64: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-" LINE
>   1: -y)
>           ^
>
> psql:bingo-pg-install.sh:67: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-" LINE
>   1: -pglibdir)
>           ^
>
> psql:bingo-pg-install.sh:69: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "*" LINE
>   1: *)
>           ^
>
> psql:bingo-pg-install.sh:70: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "usage"
>   LINE 1: usage;

Comment: You are trying to feed a shell script to the database - no wonder it barfs.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, Yes I understand, but in the installation guide that's how the step is mentioned and I'm clueless as to how to make a shell script execute for a postgresql db?

Comment: You need to run that shell script from - well - the (bash) shell, not from `psql`. So `$ ./bingo-pg-install.sh` instead of `$ psql ... -f ...`

Comment: I don't know anything about Bingo (the software), but have you tried consulting the documentation or contacting the authors rather than following a questionable tutorial?